# Can i include external style sheet into php file, if yes, how?

Tags: css

I have written all my CSS styles into a .css file; now I want to include that CSS file into a PHP file. I have tried this:

```
<link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Is your `.css` file in the same folder of your `php` file?

Comment: Show some of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to include external javascript and css files in your php code

```
<?php
   //include CSS Style Sheet
   echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='path-to-css-file' />";

   //include a javascript file
   echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='path-to-javascript-file'></script>";
?>
```

If you want to include the javascript and css source code inside the php file itself then you can do it like this

```
<?php
   //include CSS Style Sheet
   echo "<style type='text/css'>
      table{
         border: 1px solid;
         color: blue;
      } 

      /*heading class*/
      .heading1 {
         font size: 10px;
      }
   </style>";

   //include a javascript file
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
      /* All your javascript code goes here*/
   </script>";
?>
```

Comment: Great, You can mark the answer as correct. So, the question can be stated as closed

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a closing tag for `link` elements, e.g.:

```
<link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

It should use a self closing tag, like so:

```
<link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Remove the closing `</link>`, as this is not required.

**Also,** make sure that your page and `login.css` are in the same directory, or in other words, the path for CSS file should be correct.

To include it into PHP page, you'll need to print this to browser using `echo`:

```
echo '<link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
```

Comment: However, the invalid closing tag `</link>` shouldn't affect the CSS. The problem is somewhere else...

Comment: This code is for namal HTML document. But the person asking about it confused how to use it in php I think so, <?php
   //include CSS Style Sheet
   echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='path-to-css-file' />";

   //include a javascript file
   echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='path-to-javascript-file'></script>";
?>

Comment: @ROX : yup..i assume OP is not `echo`ing it...just updated answer...but `</link>` is also important part...!! :)